# Bizarre indentation

Tags: html, css

I have this JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ThYBS/
and when I run it on the JSFiddle site everything is displaying fine, but when I display it on my local machine there is a random indentation before the left word.
The word part where it should be where I can't find any issues is with the

```
#menu ul {}
```

but I can't seem to find anything.

I have no idea why, can you guys check on your side too? and let me know if you know a reason?
Thanks!

Regards

Matthew

Comment: JSfiddle normalizes your CSS by default. If you remove it there is an indentation - http://jsfiddle.net/ThYBS/1/

Comment: Aha, thank you.. well then as per http://jsfiddle.net/ThYBS/1/ do you have any idea why it's indenting like that?

Comment: because it's the default browser behavior.. To eliminate those kind of discrepancies it's a good idea to use some kind off [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well - the default browser behavior seems to be to indent items within a `<menu>` tag. Removing the padding with `{padding: 0px;}` or using a CSS reset/CSS normalize should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Adjusting the UL's Padding to 0 helped.

Comment: I believe the problem is indented code, and not rendering the html+css.